# Android : Padding is gone when android:fitsSystemWindows is true - Lollipop

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-4.4-kitkat

Here is my `layout.xml` for splash screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/splash_padding_bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/splash_padding_left"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/splash_padding_right"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/splash_padding_top">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/splash_title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            />

         <TextView
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/splash_greetings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Hi\nthere,\ngood\nevening!"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and `styles.xml` (values-v21)

```
<resources>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now, when I ran the app on kitkat the splash screen was getting displayed properly but when I ran it on Lollipop all the padding I have given to `RelativeLayout` was gone.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior, padding top and padding bottom are overwritten by the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

You can find more by reading Ian Lake's Medium post on fitsSystemWindows:
https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.nljqv5yh8

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:margin` instead